# TFS 2015 and SQL Server 2016 compatibility

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015, sql-server-2016

On this page: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements

It is stated that TFS 2015 supports SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014. Is it so that SQL Server 2016 is not supported, or is that page just not updated?

Comment: Probably just hasn't been fully regression tested yet, and even if it has, documentation changes roll out slowly (usually those are written as minimum requirements, not bookends). In any case, I can't think of any breaking changes, though, that would make the behavior any different (I mean, [the list is tiny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked the link you provided and it has been updated to show that TFS 2015 is supported on SQL 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Although SQL Server 2016 is now supported with TFS 2015 Update 3, at present, the TFS Server licence only specifies SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition.

So I guess this leads to the obvious question: when will a licence for SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition be subsumed in the TFS 2015 Server licence?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the supported SQL Server version for TFS 2015 are:

- SQL Server 2014
- SQL Server 2012 (minimum SP1)

It's recommended to use the versions above, as they are full tested and stable.

Comment: TFS 2015 Update 3 now supports SQL Server 2016.